# Is $(\Vert x \Vert_0-y)^2$ lower semi-continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, optimization

Define $\Vert x \Vert_0$, the $L_0$ norm of $x$, to be 1 when $x\neq 1$ and 0 when $x=0$. Let $y \in \mathbb{R}$. Is the function $F(x,y)=(\Vert x \Vert_0-y)^2$ lower semi-continuous? I think it is based on the definition of lower semi-continuous. Can anybody confirm that or disprove it?

Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is **NO**. Here is the counterexample:

> Observe that $F(x,1) = (1-1)^2 = 0$ when $x>0$.
>   However, $$F(0,1) = (0-1)^2=1>0 = \varliminf_{x\to 0^+} F(x,1).$$

Comment: I am new here and got an *unaccepted* for my answer. Can anybody explain what is wrong with my counterexample, in particular, E.J.?